# user _id doesn't have a default value laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

user_id doesn't have a default value that's is the error I'm getting when I clicked on the clone button and also user_id is fillable livewire movie show components

```php
public function clone(Movie $movie)
{
    $cloneMovie = $movie->replicate();
    $cloneMovie->cloned_movie_id = $movie->id;
    $cloneMovie->save();
}
```

livewire movie show blade view

```html
<div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="p-1 bg-white rounded-md">
            <div class="flex justify-between p-2 mb-2 text-white bg-gray-400 rounded-md">
                <h3 class="font-bold text-white text-md">{{ $movie->title }}</h3>
                <span class="text-xs">100 views</span>
            </div>

            <img src="{{ asset('/assets/images/blog/img-1.jpg') }}" alt="" class="w-auto rounded-md">
            <p class="p-2">{{ $movie->body }}</p>
         <button wire:click="clone({{ $movie->id }})">clone</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `user_id`?

Comment: I'm trying to clone an existing post that's already has a user_id

Comment: Where is the post ? Here i can only see Movie object. Maybe the error is generating from somewhere else ?

Comment: I mean the movie already  exists and it has user_id so I'm trying to clone the movie

Comment: check the question it's there public function clone(){}

Comment: No, it's not. `Clone` is a function but you also have `$movie->replicate();`

Comment: @Peppermintology I don't really get your question but can you directly on ways possible to clone a movie in live wire show blade

Comment: The error you're getting is because you're trying to save an object to the database which doesn't have a value for a field that requires a value. So if you're manually assigning values in `replicate()` and you're not assigning the `user_id` in there, that could be the issue.

Comment: please can you show me the example or code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237977/discussion-between-basic-and-peppermintology).

Answer (score 0):

```
$cloneMovie->push();
```

Is what you’re looking for.